# Is this Relational algebra correct?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have a databases test tomorrow and am hoping someone can confirm this answer for me. Say I have a schema of this:

```
branch (branch_name, branch_city, assets)
customer (customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
account (account_number, branch_name, balance)
loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
depositor (customer_name, account_number)
borrower (customer_name, loan_number)
```

The question I am curious about is:
"Find the names of all customers who have a loan of more than £5000 but no account with a balance of more than £500."

Original code:

```
π customer_name
  (σ amount > 5,000 ^ balance < 500 
    (borrower ⋈ loan ⋈ depositor ⋈ account))
```

Edit: Having looked at Erwin Smout's advice, I've amended my code to the following:

```
π customer_name
  (σ amount > 5,000 (borrower ⋈ loan))
-
π customer_name
  (σ balance < 500 (depositor ⋈ account))
```

Is that correct?

Comment: This seems like college homework. Can you setup a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example?

Comment: Hi Ryan. Would sqlfiddle work, as I'm not running a real SQL query, but a relational algebraic one?

Comment: Probably not. How would you know when it worked? How would you test it? Do you write a proof? This would be a better question for [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have no data for any of my questions (and no database created for them either). I have been doing SQL queries but for relational algebra we've just been doing it mentally. I'm pretty sure my query above is correct, just wanted to confirm it as there's so many natural joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just answer my own question as I now know it is correct. Thanks to everyone who helped:

```
π customer_name (σ amount > 5,000 (borrower ⋈ loan))    
-
π customer_name (σ balance < 500 (depositor ⋈ account))
```

Answer (score 3):

No it is not correct.  The phrasing "but [do not have an] account ..." is indicative that you should be using the relational difference operator somewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought, but although my query looks funny I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I'm not sure how to use the set difference query in this query. Any ideas?

Comment: Queries will always "work".  That does not mean that it is also the correct solution to any given problem.  Your query gives you the names of customers who have some loan of >5000, AS WELL AS an account of <500.  See how that is different from the given problem ?

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm just not sure how to solve it. Will hit the books.

Comment: Hi Erwin. I've amended my expression. I don't suppose you could take a look at it? Thanks for your help so far.